# ipython: print complete output history

Tags: python, ipython

By using the following command, I can acccess the complete history of ipython console inputs:

```
%history -g
```

Is there also a way to access the all outputs? I don't mean the current session, but the all time history.

Update: apparently I used wrong terminology. What I mean with 'output' is the results of print statements, generated images and what is written to external (text) files.

Comment: "the all time history." you may have to query the database directly

Comment: Which database do you mean? Is that history.py?

Comment: No, it's usually located in something like `~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite`, it's a sqlite database that actually contains all the history

Comment: `history` only applies to inputs.  Inputs are strings, and can be stored in a database.  Outputs are the display of python objects, including arrays.  They cannot be stored in a global database.  Once a session is closed, those objects no longer exist, and thus cannot be displayed.

Comment: @hpaulj heh, although an `output_history` table exists in mine, `select count(*) from output_history;` gives `0`

Comment: @hpauld I see my inputs in the same window as outputs: for example, I usually use Spyder and then I press F5 to run an algorithm. Then the Ipython console says which algorithm I gave as input and also it prints the results of print statements. Since that is all in the same screen, wouldn’t it be saved in the same file?

Comment: @Riemann no, that isn't how it works at all.

Comment: So its impossible?

Comment: The display of a `print` is not part of either an `IN` or and `Out`.

Comment: There is a `%store` magic, which uses `pickle` to save specific variables.

Comment: How many sessions does `%store` go back? And do variables get overwritten if you assign them again, so that you can’t find back that previous value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big user of `hist`.  Mostly I just use it get a clean copy of a previous line, especially one that defines a function.  I use `_` and `_n` and `Out[n]` often to fetch previous output (objects).

First an command line without output, followed by one with:

```
In [70]: x = np.arange(10)
In [71]: x
Out[71]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

That output IS the `x` created in 70:

```
In [72]: Out[71]
Out[72]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [73]: x is Out[71]
Out[73]: True
```

`print` does not produce an `Out`:

```
In [74]: print(x)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
In [75]: _74
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[75], line 1
----> 1 _74

NameError: name '_74' is not defined
In [76]: _73
Out[76]: True
In [77]: Out[73]
Out[77]: True
```

The input strings can be accessed with:

```
In [79]: _i73
Out[79]: 'x is Out[71]'
```

`%history` accesses these variables via the `history_manager` - see its code.

`Out` is a `dict`:

```
In [85]: type(Out)
Out[85]: dict
In [86]: Out.keys()
Out[86]: dict_keys([2, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 26, 28, 30, 38, 41, 43, 44, 45, 47, 50, 51, 55, 56, 57, 71, 72, 73, 76, 77, 78, 79, 82, 84, 85])
```

`In` is a list:

```
In [91]: In[-10:]
Out[91]: 
['_71',
 'x',
 'Out.keys()',
 'type(Out)',
 'Out.keys()',
 'type(In)',
 'In',
 'In[-4]',
 'In[-4:]',
 'In[-10:]']
```

Answer (score -2):

just run `%history` without `-g` -g is for specific pattern [reference](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.history.html)

Comment: I tried this but it does not work: 1. It does not give output but input 2. it only gives input of current session

Comment: history only applies to input strings